# I'm confused on how current will flow in this system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

I'm working with the following circuit:

[image: complete circuit]

So, I thought that it might be a good idea to work with each mesh separetely. And then I did the following:

[image]

But i'm really not sure if this is the correct approach when using the Kirchhoff's law. I'm really confused on how the current will flow if I separate it. Should I understand how current will flow BEFORE separing or can I do it after?

Comment: The whole point of Kirchhoff's laws is to find the currents, so there's certainly no need to determine the current directions before applying Kirchhoff's laws. Just write down all the loop and junction equations and solve.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the currents here is by using mesh analysis. You arbitrarily assign mesh currents to essential meshes i.e a loop not containing any other smaller loop. Then by using Kirchoff's voltage law, you solve for the currents.

I recommend [Fundamentals of Electric Circuits By Alexander and Sadiku](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Fundamentals_of_Electric_Circuits.html?id=JOgeAQAAIAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use delta star method to to simplify the loop with the resistors R4 R6 R7 . Current analysis would become very easy.